# How to model a proportion using caret in R?

Tags: r, r-caret, glm, modeling

I am trying to model a proportion (or probability), i.e. a continuous variable bounded between 0 and 1 (inclusive) using `caret`.

In my [previous post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637575/modelling-a-proportion-1-0), I've been told to use a logistic regression (i.e. `glm()` with `family = "binomial`).

I would like to use the `caret` framework with k-fold cross validation.

However, caret doesn't work with the code below, although I have no problem using `stats::glm()` on its own. The data below is purely for reproducibility.

```r
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: lattice

data("USArrests")

#New Data Points with 0 and 100 % urban population
newstate1 <- matrix(c(7, 100, 0, 10),
                    nrow = 1,
                    dimnames =
                      list("New State 1", colnames(USArrests)))

newstate2 <- matrix(c(7, 100, 100, 10),
                    nrow = 1,
                    dimnames =
                      list("New State 2", colnames(USArrests)))

USArrests <- rbind(USArrests, newstate1, newstate2)

# As a proportion
USArrests$UrbanPop <- USArrests$UrbanPop /100


ctrl <- trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 5,
  classProbs = TRUE
)

train(
  formula = UrbanPop ~ .,
  data = USArrests,
  method = "glm",
  family = "binomial",
  trControl = ctrl,
  metric = "ROC"
)
#> Warning in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): cannnot compute class
#> probabilities for regression
#> Error in evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, : train()'s use of ROC codes requires class probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()

#the below works:
glm(
  formula = UrbanPop ~ .,
  data = USArrests,
  family = "binomial")
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You may have misunderstood the approach proposed in the linked CV answer. You should do logistic regression on the underlying 0/1 data if you have them. You mention `glm` works, though you must getting a warning - "non-integer successes". I *think* you have numerator data with a constant denominator of 100. In that case (though I am not 100% sure it is), try binomial regression, of which logistic is a special case, and interpret the results as you would logistic (ie, with the *untransformed / original* `UrbanPop` try `glm(cbind(100, UrbanPop) ~ ., data = USArrests, family = "binomial")`)

Comment: @jpsmith The warning message shouldn't be a problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953045/warning-non-integer-successes-in-a-binomial-glm-survey-packages). Do you have your solution working with `caret`?

Comment: Unless I'm missing some key piece of information, you're telling R to run a logistic regression on a continuous variable; that's a pretty basic flaw, and the warning message is telling you that. You are also not adhering to the recommendations on the CV post, which say you can recreate the underlying 1/0 binary data (no where does it say divide into a proportion and run logistic regression on that proportion). I strongly suggest you heed the warning message. It, as well as I, are just trying to help. As the comment to your linked SO answer states, it may prevent you from doing something silly.

Comment: @jpsmith thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I cannot make your suggestion ("binomial regression") work with the caret framework. Is it working for you?